# Prolog: add list to set

Tags: prolog

The below predicate adds item X to list S.  It works fine.

```
addToSet(X, S, S) :-
    atomic(X),
    member(X, S),
    !.
addToSet(X, S, [X|S]) :-
    atomic(X).
```

I am trying to extend it to a predicate which adds list [H|T] to set S.  It works perfect if [H|T] is only 2 items long... i.e. if T is also atomic.

```
addToSet([], S, S).
addToSet([H,T], S, S2) :-
    addToSet(H, S, S1),
    addToSet(T, S1, S2).
```

For example, addToSet([5,6],[1,2,3,4],X). works as I desire.  However, addToSet([5,6,7],[1,2,3,4],X). does not work at all.  I am stumped... there is obviously something wrong with the last 2-3 lines of my code, but I cannot figure it out.  Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: consider checking the set-related predicates (if it exists in your prolog system) for swi-prolog, here are some http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.12%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/lists.html%27%29%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`addToSet([H,T], S, S2)` should be `addToSet([H|T], S, S2)`. As it is, you're matching a list containing exactly `H` and `T`, not a list with head `H` and tail `T`. Looks like just a typo.

Comment: Wow... so embarrassing.  I swear I stared at this thing for over an hour thinking it had to be a simple typo.  Cannot believe I missed that.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Happens to the best of us. :)